# Pointers and 2d arrays

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, matrix, char

For the next code snippet:

```
char words[10][9] = {
"Hello",
"Good-bye"
};
```

The expression `words[2][4]` would give me the character `'o'`, but I don't understand why.

Can anybody explain this behavior?

Comment: what language is this in?

Comment: Assuming this is C, then you're seeing undefined behaviour.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth - question is, if this is a global or static variable, isn't this supposed to return a `0`?

Comment: @ysap: Actually, yes, you're right.  So the OP needs to give us a test-case, or it didn't happen!

Comment: Even a local variable has to have a zero at "non-initialized" elements. In C there is no partial initialization: either all elements are initialized (possibly to `0`) or no elements are initialized. see http://ideone.com/JDv86w

Comment: @Lior: Huh? The initialization you posted will *not* give you character `'o'` in `words[2][4]`. It will initialize `words[2][4]` with zero. Something tells me you need a better developer's font on your system to be able to tell `'o'` from `0`.

Comment: @AndreyT: It's not possible for him to "not be able to tell" 'o' from 0. If he uses the numeric value, one is 0, the other is 111. If he tries to print the character, one will print "o", the other won't print anything.

Comment: @newacct: Well, maybe he's looking at the array content in the debugger. The debugger shows `0`, which he for some reason mistakes for an `o`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a *"partial" initialization*, all the *"uninitialized"* elements are effectively initialized with `0`.

So your element should have a value of `0` (or `'\0'`).

If it hasn't there is something else going on that you do not show us.

**In C there is no partial initialization: either all elements are initialized (possibly to 0) or no elements are initialized.**

See http://ideone.com/JDv86w or http://ideone.com/j6BIRP

Comment: Then what may cause it print a character 'o'   ?

Comment: I guess that between the initialization and the printing, the memory address is being overwritten with the `'o'`.

Comment: man. I am not the question poster.  :P

Comment: @Sibi: hehe. previous comment edited :)